# Connecting git repository to redmine subproject

Tags: git, redmine

I have redmine 2.2.3 and a git repository in `/var/www/`

There is no problem when I'm connecting the whole git repository in redmine 
with the link `/var/www/.git`.

The problem is that I want to link a subproject in redmine to the exact project in `/var/www`

For example there is a project in `/var/www/project2`, how can I link exactly `/var/www/project2` in redmine?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do that. The problem is that Git treats whole repo as a solid structure  and cant use partial trees of the repo (unlike Subversion). So Redmine just uses git bindings to scan the repo. The possible solution will be a collection of repositories for each project, or you can make use of [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: I would go further and say, although you technically can use git submodules to do that, it is likely overkill for your scenario. In most cases you are better off using the one git repository with multiple Redmine projects.